# How to set up Access database as a back-end only

Tags: excel, ms-access

I plan on using Excel as the front-end and Access as the back-end only. (all queries and forms are in Excel).  A single Access database will be queried from multiple Excel files that will be located on the share drive (Linux server).  Access tables contain memo, text and number fields.
Data will be sent to Access tables and records will be appended/deleted; all via Excel.

There will be multiple users interacting with a single Access database via multiple Excel files located on the shared drive. Users will be interacting from different workstations with Windows 7, all have Access 2010 and Excel 2010 installed.

This process works for me from my workstation but I’m not sure what will happen when other 4 people will be sending/appending/deleting records to the same Database?
How do I make this work? What settings do I need to check in Access to make this possible?

Any advice will be greatly appreciated since I’m fairly new to Access.

Thank you!

Comment: If all you need is the back-end then why not MS SQL? As a stop-gap Access could be used as an alternate 'dashboard' with linked tables.

Comment: Sorry, but I need to make it work with Access.  Do you know if this will work with Access? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Access is a file-server, and not a data-server.
That's means when you do a query on an Access database, all the data are going to the client part, who process the query.
Let a query "get the books written by Kernighan" in your Excel. Excel will ask to Access (throught the ADO or DAO) : "send me all the books". Access will send ALL the books, and Excel will find the book written by Kernighan.

In the same way, if Excel (still with ADO / DAO) want to make an update, it does it localy. The Access database will just set up a flag to prevent conflicts. (btw, this flag is stored in the .laccdb file)

In your case, all that are done by the ADO/DAO layer, which will

- send all the data
- set a flag to prevent the conflicts if one data is in Edit mode

So, to be short : yes, you can do it ;)

Comment: I have already built the whole project and it works well for me.  However, one of the users tried to send  data to my Access database and he wasn't able to from his workstation, It was read only for him.  I know very little about Access and would like to know if I need to set any special settings so multiple users could perform all the operations that I can? There will be only 5 users but multiple Excel files all liked to the same database.  Everything is on a shared drive. Basically, I’m trying to overt a disaster. Thank you

Comment: I also would like to know how slow it will be to query Access from Excel once I have 1 million rows of data(seconds, minutes)? Thanks

Comment: Access does NOT send ALL data to the client for a query. This is a fairly common misconception. What is sent to the client depends on the system design and the where clause of the query.

Comment: How slow your system will be depends on its design as well as your network. Good system design + good network design + fast network + good maintenance + good hardware = good performance. Be aware that Access has a file size limit of 2GB. If you are going to regularly be sending 1 million rows across the network, the speed will depend more on the network than on the BE.

Comment: Does all your users have the same front-end ? If not, I suspect a slightly difference in the connexion string or the recordset definition.

Do you use DAO or ADO ?

Comment: As AVG says, Access don't send all the data on each queries. It's depend on the query itself and the cache, but it's the case in many case.

To know how your system will slow down with a 1 millions rows table, you have to do a load test because it depends of many factors (including the position of your access file in your directories)